# Возможности options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

есть

```
.origin.select
  select#origin
    = options_from_collection_for_select(Airport.all, :id, :name)
```

HTML получается каким

```
<option value="1">Natl</option>
```

Можно ли как то в `options_from_collection_for_select` для option задать отображение не только по `:name` но и по нескольким полям типа так:

```
= options_from_collection_for_select(Airport.all, :id, ("#{:name} #{:city}(#{:country})")
```

Что бы получилось как то так

```
<option value="1">Natl Brussels(Belgium)</option>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В классе, откуда вы извлекаете данные Airport следует реализовать метод, скажем full_name, который будет возвращать строку, эквивалентную той, которую вы хотите вызывать

```
class Airport 

  def full_name
    # Тут формируете нужный вам формат вывода
    "#{self.name} #{self.city}(#{self.country})"
  end

end
```

тогда вы можете вызвать этот новый метод, передав в третьем параметре символ с его именем

```
.origin.select
  select#origin
    = options_from_collection_for_select(Airport .all, :id, :full_name)
```

Comment: А у вас что за коллекция? Вы её в Object храните? Может выделить какой-то отдельный класс? Если у вас рельсы, то просто создайте модель, не наследуя её от ActiveRecord:Base, просто обычный класс в моделях и храните эту коллекцию в ней.

Comment: Если такой модели нет (например, не заводили, потому что нет таблицы базы данных), я бы завел и хранил бы коллекцию аэропортов прямо в ней. Если нет таблицы, прямо бы массив захардкодил. Если есть таблица и соответствующая модель, еще лучше, вместо Object лучше задействовать её. А чтобы подтянуть город и страну, добавить ассоциации с моделями City и Counrty, для аэропортов belongs_to, а для городов и стран has_many

Comment: а Object это просто к примеру было)) вообще вот оригинал `= options_from_collection_for_select(Airport.all, :iata, :full_name)`

Comment: А тогда все нормально. Просто от Object все классы наследуются, я подумал вы его открыли и пропатчили :) Можно так поведение всех классов изменить, только об этом хотел предупредить. Если у вас собственный класс - все хорошо.